# Installing poppler with fink on Mac OSX Mountain Lion does not seem to install pdftotext utility

Tags: pdftotext, poppler, fink

I want to install pdftotext on MacOSX. I much prefer fink to other package installers. I used:

```
fink install poppler46
```

thinking pdftotext might be included (as it is when using brew install poppler) but it didn't seem to be. Should pdftotext have been installed and, if so, where?

I've now gone down the route of installing Homebrew but Fink and Homebrew don't seem to co-exist very happily.

Comment: Did you see my answer? Does it work for you, @user1718097?

Answer (score 1):

The package you want to install most likely is called `poppler-bin`, or `poppler46-bin`, or `poppler46-shlibs`.

`poppler46` as a package name seems to provide the library files only.

---

<sub>Note, I'm not very familiar with Fink myself. I'm a **[MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)** user.</sub>

Comment: You are correct -- `fink install poppler-bin` installs the command line utilities.